# How to Destructure a huge JSON object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class Options extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //previously called validOptions //Whether JSON_output has been uploaded to Azure
      optionAvailbility: false,
      // dataEngineResult: null
      dataEngineResult: {
        attribute_description: {
          age: {
            name: "age",
            data_type: "Integer",
            category: {
            ...
          },
          education:{...},
          income:{...},
          ....
       }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Basically I have this huge json object that is a result obtained from azure, which I update to my state in my Option.js component.

Within this component, I want to retrieve all of the attributes via destructing.

Why is this method wrong:

```
const ageAttr, educationAttr..., incomeAttr = this.state.dataEngineResult.attribute_description
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you should use const {ageAttr, educationAttr, }

Answer (score 3):

Since `attribue_description` is an object. You should use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and use the name of the property you want to get.

```
const { age, education, income } = this.state.dataEngineResult.attribute_description
```

If you want to change the name you can do like so

```
const { age: ageAttr, education: educationAttr, income: incomeAttr } = this.state.dataEngineResult.attribute_description
```

Comment: Sorry. I think I wasn't very clear. Absolutely, I've forgetten about the proper way of destructuring where the property names have to be the same. 

However, in my current usecase, I'm actually receiving this JSON result. Today it maybe age attribute, another day it my be something else. I won't actually know. How should go about this then?

This reason why I need to do this dynamically is because I need to access nested information within my JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Destructuring** for it. Learn more about [javascript destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

If you want to use the properties from only one nested object then use below method.

```
1. const { age, education, income } = this.state.dataEngineResult.attribute_description;
```

If you want use other state properties in the function use below method.

```
2. const {dataEngineResult: {attribute_description: {age, education, income}},optionAvailbility } = this.state;
```